# Scrollview content size set to screen width max

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In my view I have a `scrollview`.
In my scrollview I have a `UILabel`.

I use constraints to set my scrollview in my superview and also for my UILabel.

If I set a long text inside my UILabel the `scrollview's content` extends to the width of my UILabel.
Instead of that, I would like the content view set to maximum width of my screen and the UILabel goes to multilines.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your label's number of line to 0 and `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` the width you want, then call `setNeedsLayout` with your main view.

Comment: preferredMaxLayoutWidth was missing, I set the value and it's ok now. thx